# how to add user control dynamically in placeholder without removing all controls which are added in placeholder?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have created user controls and register all user controls on page.On run time i am able to add user controls in placeholder and use it but when new user control is add then old control's all changes are remove and all user controls are added from initials.

Is there any way for when user control is going to added then all old user control remain with their changes in placeholder and new control will add in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**Add**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.controlcollection.add.aspx) or [**AddAt**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.controlcollection.addat.aspx) methods to add your controls in place holder.

```
YourPlaceHoderID.Controls.Add(yourcontrolObject);
```

Or

```
YourPlaceHoderID.Controls.AddAt(index, yourcontrolObject);
```

Comment: is there any way that when new control add in placeholder then old controls(which are already added in placeholder) remain in placeholder with all changes.

Comment: Use AddAt method instead of Add and give zero index to insert at first location

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i have use both method, in my case i need to first add one user control then it is working.when i am going to  add another control then page is post back and then placeholder try to add from initials(it treats like there is no user control) so old user control which already added in placeholder is again going to add and all changes which i did on it will lost.so is there any method from which old user control remain in it and new one is added. please reply i am unable to find solution of it from anywhere,thanks in advance.

Comment: Add your controls in if block of not postback like 
if(!Page.IsPostBack){ // add code }